# Linux - How do I see when a process started?

Tags: linux, process

How can I see when a process started, assuming I know the pid. (On Linux)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you want only the start time, you can select the field and suppress the header by doing this:

```
 ps -p YOURPID -o lstart=
```

the output will look like this:

```
 Mon Dec 14 17:17:16 2009
```

which is `ctime(3)` format and you can parse it to split out the relevant parts.

Other start fields such as `start`, `stime`, `bsdstart` and `start_time` age the time (after 24 hours only the date is shown, for example).

You can, however, use them directly for recently started processes without further parsing:

```
ps -p YOURPID -o stime=
```

which would output something like:

```
09:26
```

Comment: This works on a mac too!

Answer (score 9):

`awk '{print $22}' /proc/$pid/stat` - gives you the start time in jiffies after boot

Comment: Beautifully obscure answer!

Comment: Riddle me this.  A system with an uptime of '17:57' has a process with a start time of '727975'.  Looks like the process started 8 days from now?

Comment: It's actually in jiffies (100/sec)

Comment: Way too obscure! And besides, now you have to look up the boot time and do the math to convert jiffies to seconds and calculate the offset to get clock time. Easy, but too many steps. See Chopper3's answer.

Comment: The amount of jiffies per second is stored in system variable HZ. It is mostly 100. To calculate it in shell you might use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524937/1950345

Answer (score 8):

"ps -f" - it's in the man pages

Comment: And to select the known pid: `ps -f -p yourpid`

Comment: Actually this works if the process was started the same day, but if it was started another day you only get the day, but not the time of day as on @DennisWilliamson answer

Answer (score 0):

If there's a single process with a given name (e.g. `openvpn`) on the host, you can do:

```
ps -p `pgrep openvpn` -o lstart=
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Dennis Williamson's excellent answer, the `ps` command also has the `-O` option which, according to the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html): is "Like -o, but preloaded with some default columns." This allows you to grep for the command (program) associated with the PID, if you don't know the PID itself.

Example: finding when an `apt-get` process hanging on Debian/Ubuntu started:

```
ps -A -O lstart= | grep apt-get | grep -v grep
```

Piping to `grep -v grep` filters out lines containing the string "grep", which removes the command we just typed in (since we don't want it).

On my system right now, this gives:

```
1461407  Apr 15 06:00:00 2021 S ?        00:05:09 apt-get autoremove -y
```

Answer (score -2):

one way you can `ps -f |grep <pid>` as you said you the pid otherwise you can see in top also

Comment: This will match far more things than planned. `ps` has the `--pid` option to pass directly a specific pid you are interested in.