# Is there a way to determine what time a process was started on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux - How do I see when a process started?](https://serverfault.com/questions/95643/linux-how-do-i-see-when-a-process-started)

```
ps -ef
```

shows the date that the process started.  I'd like to see the date and the time if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ps -eo pid,user,cmd,lstart
```

I think you want lstart, the time displayed with -eF is bsdstart which shows time in Month Day only if more than 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
ps -eF
```

Comment: ps -ef doesn't seem to show the time for processes that were not started today.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the creation time of the process in /proc/, by looking at the creation time of the process's status file :

```
ls -lc /proc/<pid>/status
```

This gives you both the date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'ps' or you can pull it from proc.

Additionally, /proc/$PID/stat has a field (either 10 or 22, I don't remember) which gives you a representation of start time from boot in jiffies. Edit.. Like someone else said, I had always thought the mtime of /proc/$PID/stat was a valid measure, but it doesn't seem to jibe:

```
[jeff@marvin 1]$ stat /proc/1/stat
  File: `/proc/1/stat'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   regular empty file
Device: 3h/3d   Inode: 1661623     Links: 1
Access: (0444/-r--r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2010-03-15 16:31:16.391415019 -0400
Modify: 2010-03-15 16:31:16.391415019 -0400
Change: 2010-03-15 16:31:16.391415019 -0400
```

That gives me a start of March 15th, but `ps -ef` reports differently:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Jan07 ?        00:00:02 /sbin/init
```

The `ps` command is most likely doing the jiffy math, and according to my uptime, it looks to be the most correct.

```
[jeff@marvin 1]$ uptime
 10:31:52 up 70 days, 17:22,  7 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
[jeff@marvin 1]$
```